# How to know if Smarty is really activated on WordPress?

Tags: smarty

On WP 5.6 / CiviCRM 5.32 we can't succeed to send HTML e-mails using css in `<style>` and `{literal}` (see [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38154/send-email-in-html-on-wordpress/38256#38256)) knowing that we succeed in sending html templates with in-line css.

Smarty is set on '1' in civicrm.settings.php but my question is if smarty is "really" activated and if there's a way to check this parameter.

```
* Enable this constant, if you want to send your email through the smarty
 * templating engine(allows you to do conditional and more complex logic)
 *
 */
if (!defined('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy answer indeed :
send an e-mail with this code

```
<p>{$smarty.now|date_format}</p>
<p>{$smarty.version}</p>
```

You should get something like:

> Jan 14, 2021
>
> 2.6.31